# How to calculate all permutations of a vector that satisfy a given condition

Tags: python, r, matlab, vector, permutation

I'd like to calculate all permutations of the vector `N` taken `k` at a time. I also want to allow any element of `N` to permute with itself not only with other elements. I only want to get permutations that sum up to a given number `n`.

Here is an example in MATLAB:

```
N = [1 2 3 4];
k = 2;
n = 6;
```

For numbers above, I could reach my target by doing:

```
Perm = combvec(N, N)';
Perm = Perm(sum(Perm,2)==n,:);
Perm =

     4     2
     3     3
     2     4
```

However, `N` is expected to be up to `90` elements long and value of `k` up to `10`. This makes the above way is infeasible as it involves calculation of many permutations that are not needed.

Is there any way of doing this efficiently given the expected `N` vector length and `k`? I'm happy to consider solutions in MATLAB, R, or python.

Comment: Is N a random array or does it goes from 1 to N?

Comment: It's always 1 to `n-k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generator-based attempt that just yields the permutations one at a time instead of trying to store them all in memory. I went with a generator approach because I think with anything else you'll run out of memory, the number of permutations is huge as soon as `k` is more than about 5:

```
def find_perm(k, n, N=None):
    # Initialize N
    if N is None:
        N = list(range(1, n - k + 1))

    if k == 0:
        return []

    # Only search up to n (the current target)
    for i in N[:(n + 1)]:
        if i > n:
            continue
        if i == n:
            yield [i]
            continue
        # Recurse
        sub_perms = find_perm(k - 1, n - i, N[:(n + 1)])

        for sub_perm in sub_perms:
            perm = [i] + sub_perm
            if sum(perm) == n:
                yield perm
```

Example output:

```
list(find_perm(2, 6))
# [[2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2]]

# Too many to store, just printing a few
big_perms = find_perm(10, 100)
for i in range(5):
    print(next(big_perms))
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 90]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 89]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 88]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 87]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 86]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your question is whether there is an efficient way to find all 10-element subsets of {1, 2, ..., 90}, with repeats allowed, that sum to 100.

It is easy enough to count how many such subsets exist:

```
N <- 1:90  # values we can select
k <- 10  # num to select (repeats allowed)
n <- 100  # target
num <- matrix(NA, n, k) # (i,j) is number of subsets of size j summing to i
num[,1] <- as.numeric(1:n %in% N)  # base case
for (kval in 2:k) {
  num[,kval] <- sapply(1:n, function(jval) {
    sum(num[intersect(1:n, jval-N),kval-1])
  })
}
num[n,k]  # Number of combinations
# [1] 1.731031e+12
```

So you are asking if there is an efficient way to compute and output a set of 1.73 trillion length-10 vectors. I would argue the answer is no -- that is an astronomical number of vectors to output, store, or manipulate.

Comment: Actually, it's much easier to count number of subsets. This is a permutation with repetition problem. Therefore, the number of distinguishable permutations are `n^k`. My question was about finding a practical way to compute needed permutations only rather than the whole sets and then filter them. Thanks anyway